# Construction of a bijection between set T of infinite binary strings and R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) on Wikipedia is the example of how to construct a bijection between $T$ - set of infinite binary strings and $\Bbb{R}$. For me the method of building of such bijection is interesting but I want more details on the part of building the bijection between $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$. Specifically:

1. How Cantor removed countably infinite sets from $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$? While I know that every infinite set contains infinite countable subset - it seems to me that if I remove a countable subset from infinite set I will still have infinite set from where I can again remove countable subset. Infinitely repeating it with no "damage" to the power of the infinite set.

   1.1. Why Cantor even bothered removing countably infinite subsets from each $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$?
2. Why do we need a family of functions $f_b(t)$?

   > Constructing a bijection between $T$ and $\Bbb{R}$ is slightly more complicated. Instead of mapping $0111...$ to the decimal $0.0111...$, it can be mapped to the base b number: $0.0111..._b$. This leads to the family of functions: $f_b(t) = 0.t_b$. The functions $f_b(t)$ are injections, except for $f_2(t)$. This function will be modified to produce a bijection between $T$ and $\Bbb{R}$.

I am looking for the advice on where can I find this topic described in details?

Comment: for 1, I dont know how Cantor did it, but if you remove the rationals Q from the closed interval C, and from the open interval I, the resulting set is just the irrationals for both sets (ie C\Q=I\Q). So we have a bijection between those sets, and we can construct a bijection between the sets we removed,because they are both enumerable.

Comment: Paulo's trick works, but ultimately what you'll want to do is get comfortable with the [**Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) (which does *not* require anything weird like the axiom of choice, incidentally). We have the trivial injection $(0,1)\rightarrow [0,1]$, and the map $$x\mapsto {x+1\over 3}$$ gives an injection $[0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$, so by CSB we get that they have the same cardinality. CSB is an extremely useful tool to have for this sort of thing (and is why we get to be so cavalier about building bijections).